# Extracting part of string located after second occurrence of specific character and second occurrence of another character

Tags: php, regex, string

How can extract piece of string which is located between second occurrence of the ":" character and second occurrence of "," in piece of string?

substr() can't help me, since the length of the peace of the string that I want to extract may vary. I am not posting any code, since I have no clue where to start from. I am searching string manipulation functions, but without any luck so far. I am not sure if this can be done with regular expressions either, since it is second concurrence.

Here is the part of the string that I am trying to manipulate

```
[3] => 93,text:Πού είναι αυτή η πόλη:,photo:c083,correct:2,answers:[{text:Βενεζουέλα.,correct:false},{text:Βραζιλία.,correct:false},{text:Πέρυ.,correct:true}]},{
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of the string you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: i have updated my question, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I suspect there are better patterns you could be looking for in that string. What's the result you want?

Comment: I want to get the c083 in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id try something like the following assuming you're always trying to get the `photo` value:

```
$str = "93,text:Πού είναι αυτή η πόλη:,photo:c083,correct:2,answers:[{text:Βενεζουέλα.,correct:false},{text:Βραζιλία.,correct:false},{text:Πέρυ.,correct:true}]},{";
preg_match_all('/photo:[\w+]*/', $str, $match);
$photo = explode(':', $match[0][0]);
$photo_id = $photo[1];
echo $photo_id;
// > c083
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am checking your code now, it seem that this may work,just let me ensure that I get the correct results, since this is an array with about 1500 results....

Comment: Great, now I will try to re-use your code to get the answers1, 2,3...I may have until 5 of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There must be better way of doing this ,but at least I make it to work:

```
        //$question contain the string posted in my question
        preg_match_all('/photo:/', $question,$position3, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);  

        preg_match_all('/,/', $question,$position4, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); 

        // I was looking for the 3rd occurence of : after all
        // so change the [2] with [1] if you are looking for second
        // occurennce
        $pos3 = $position3[0][2][1] +1;
        $pos4 = $position4[0][2][1] +1;

        $startIndex = min($pos3, $pos4);
        $length = abs($pos3 - $pos4);

        $photo = substr($question, $startIndex, $length);
        $photo = strstr($photo, 'photo');
        $photo = strstr($photo, ':');
        $photo = str_replace (":","",$photo);
        $photo = str_replace (",","",$photo);
        $photo = $photo.".jpg";
        $photo = trim($photo);
```

This code can be much shorter & cleaner, and I will try to update this code once when I clean this mess, but fell free to post better & shorter options.